# unaligned tikz nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying a picture with following code :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes, positioning,intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=-\pgflinewidth]

\coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
\coordinate (xEnd) at (0,4);
\coordinate (yEnd) at (10.5,0);

\tikzset{
  mybox/.style = {
     minimum height=#1, 
     minimum width=1.5cm, 
     inner sep=3pt, 
     rotate=90,
     draw},
  mybox/.default=10.5cm,
}

\draw[->,thick, name path=xaxis] (origin) -- node [above,rotate=90] {Processors} (xEnd);
\draw[->,thick, name path=yaxis] (origin) -- node [below] {Time} (yEnd);

\node (src) at (0.5,3) [mybox=0.4cm] {\large $src$};
\node (r0) [mybox=0.7cm,below=of src] {\large $radix_0$};
\node (r1) [mybox=0.7cm,below=of r0] {\large $radix_1$};
\node (r2) [mybox=0.7cm,below=of r1] {\large $radix_2$};
\node (r3) [mybox=0.7cm,below=of r2] {\large $radix_3$};
\node (r4) [mybox=0.7cm,below=of r3] {\large $radix_4$};
\node (r5) [mybox=0.7cm,below=of r4] {\large $radix_5$};

\node (r6)  [mybox=0.7cm,below=of r5,xshift=-2cm] {\large $radix_6$};
\node (r7)  [mybox=0.7cm,below=of r6] {\large $radix_7$};
\node (r8)  [mybox=0.7cm,below=of r7] {\large $radix_8$};
\node (r9)  [mybox=0.7cm,below=of r8] {\large $radix_9$};
\node (r10)  [mybox=0.7cm,below=of r9] {\large $radix_{10}$};
\node (op)  [mybox=0.4cm,below=of r10] {\large $output$};

\node (Bsrc) [mybox=0.4cm,below =of r5,fill=gray!50] {\large $src$};
\node (Br0) [mybox=0.7cm,below=of Bsrc,fill=gray!50] {\large $radix_0$};
\node (Br1) [mybox=0.7cm,below=of Br0,fill=gray!50] {\large $radix_1$};
\node (Br2) [mybox=0.7cm,below=of Br1,fill=gray!50] {\large $radix_2$};
\node (Br3) [mybox=0.7cm,below=of Br2,fill=gray!50] {\large $radix_3$};
\node (Br4) [mybox=0.7cm,below=of Br3,fill=gray!50] {\large $radix_4$};
\node (Br5) [mybox=0.7cm,below=of Br4,fill=gray!50] {\large $radix_5$};

\node (r6)  at (0.65,1) [mybox=0.7cm,fill=gray!80] {\large $radix_6$};
\node (r7)  [mybox=0.7cm,below=of r6,fill=gray!80] {\large $radix_7$};
\node (r8)  [mybox=0.7cm,below=of r7,fill=gray!80] {\large $radix_8$};
\node (r9)  [mybox=0.7cm,below=of r8,fill=gray!80] {\large $radix_9$};
\node (r10)  [mybox=0.7cm,below=of r9,fill=gray!80] {\large $radix_{10}$};
\node (op)  [mybox=0.4cm,below=of r10,fill=gray!80] {\large $output$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And it produces the following image. Now in this produced Image, I see that the alignment is wrong. You can see that the nodes are shifted little bit in vertically with respect to their neighbors. How do I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nodes are shifted by the line width (0.4pt by default). Setting the node distance or the line width to 0 removes the shifting:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes, positioning,intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0pt]

\coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
\coordinate (xEnd) at (0,4);
\coordinate (yEnd) at (10.5,0);

\tikzset{
  mybox/.style = {
     minimum height=#1, 
     minimum width=1.5cm, 
     inner sep=3pt, 
     rotate=90,
     line width=1pt,
     draw},
  mybox/.default=10.5cm,
}

\draw[->,thick, name path=xaxis] (origin) -- node [above,rotate=90] {Processors} (xEnd);
\draw[->,thick, name path=yaxis] (origin) -- node [below] {Time} (yEnd);

\node (src) at (0.5,3) [mybox=0.4cm] {\large $src$};
\node (r0) [mybox=0.7cm,below=of src.south] {\large $radix_0$};
\node (r1) [mybox=0.7cm,below=of r0] {\large $radix_1$};
\node (r2) [mybox=0.7cm,below=of r1] {\large $radix_2$};
\node (r3) [mybox=0.7cm,below=of r2] {\large $radix_3$};
\node (r4) [mybox=0.7cm,below=of r3] {\large $radix_4$};
\node (r5) [mybox=0.7cm,below=of r4] {\large $radix_5$};

\node (r6)  [mybox=0.7cm,below=of r5,xshift=-2cm] {\large $radix_6$};
\node (r7)  [mybox=0.7cm,below=of r6] {\large $radix_7$};
\node (r8)  [mybox=0.7cm,below=of r7] {\large $radix_8$};
\node (r9)  [mybox=0.7cm,below=of r8] {\large $radix_9$};
\node (r10)  [mybox=0.7cm,below=of r9] {\large $radix_{10}$};
\node (op)  [mybox=0.4cm,below=of r10] {\large $output$};

\node (Bsrc) [mybox=0.4cm,below =of r5,fill=gray!50] {\large $src$};
\node (Br0) [mybox=0.7cm,below=of Bsrc,fill=gray!50] {\large $radix_0$};
\node (Br1) [mybox=0.7cm,below=of Br0,fill=gray!50] {\large $radix_1$};
\node (Br2) [mybox=0.7cm,below=of Br1,fill=gray!50] {\large $radix_2$};
\node (Br3) [mybox=0.7cm,below=of Br2,fill=gray!50] {\large $radix_3$};
\node (Br4) [mybox=0.7cm,below=of Br3,fill=gray!50] {\large $radix_4$};
\node (Br5) [mybox=0.7cm,below=of Br4,fill=gray!50] {\large $radix_5$};

\node (r6)  at (0.65,1) [mybox=0.7cm,fill=gray!80] {\large $radix_6$};
\node (r7)  [mybox=0.7cm,below=of r6,fill=gray!80] {\large $radix_7$};
\node (r8)  [mybox=0.7cm,below=of r7,fill=gray!80] {\large $radix_8$};
\node (r9)  [mybox=0.7cm,below=of r8,fill=gray!80] {\large $radix_9$};
\node (r10)  [mybox=0.7cm,below=of r9,fill=gray!80] {\large $radix_{10}$};
\node (op)  [mybox=0.4cm,below=of r10,fill=gray!80] {\large $output$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multido,pstricks}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-0.55,-0.55)(13.7,5.2)
\psset{dimen = m}
\large
  \psline{->}(0,0)(13.7,0)
  \psline{->}(0,0)(0,5.2)
  \rput(6.85,-0.4){Time}
  \rput(-0.4,2.6){\rotateleft{Processors}}
  \psframe[fillstyle = solid, fillcolor = gray](5.3,0.3)(6.3,2.3)
  \rput(5.8,1.3){\rotateleft{output}}
  \psframe(12.3,0.3)(13.3,2.3)
  \rput(12.8,1.3){\rotateleft{output}}
  \psframe(0.3,2.8)(1.3,4.8)
  \rput(0.8,3.8){\rotateleft{src}}
  \psframe[fillstyle = solid, fillcolor = gray](6.3,2.8)(7.3,4.8)
  \rput(6.8,3.8){\rotateleft{src}}
  \psframe[fillstyle = solid, fillcolor = gray](7.3,2.8)(8.3,4.8)
  \rput(7.8,3.8){\rotateleft{$\text{radix}_{0}$}}
  \multido{
    \rA = 0.3+1,
    \rB = 7.3+1,
    \rC = 8.3+1,
    \rD = 1.3+1,
    \iB = 1+1,
    \iA = 6+1
  }{5}{
    \psframe[fillstyle = solid, fillcolor = gray](\rA,0.3)(!\rA\space 1 add 2.3)
    \rput(!\rA\space 0.5 add 1.3){\rotateleft{$\text{radix}_{\iA}$}}
    \psframe(\rB,0.3)(!\rB\space 1 add 2.3)
    \rput(!\rB\space 0.5 add 1.3){\rotateleft{$\text{radix}_{\iA}$}}
    \psframe[fillstyle = solid, fillcolor = gray](\rC,2.8)(!\rC\space 1 add 4.8)
    \rput(!\rC\space 0.5 add 3.8){\rotateleft{$\text{radix}_{\iB}$}}
    \psframe(\rD,2.8)(!\rD\space 1 add 4.8)
    \rput(!\rD\space 0.5 add 3.8){\rotateleft{$\text{radix}_{\iB}$}}
  }
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 2):

A variation of the dcmst answer, but with little bit more compact code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,chains,shapes,positioning,intersections}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=3mm and 0mm,
    start chain = going right,
mybox/.style = {
     minimum height=19mm,
     minimum width=7mm,
     inner sep=3pt, outer sep=0pt,
     font=\large,
     line width=1pt,
     draw,
     on chain,
     node contents={\rotatebox{90}{#1}},
     },
                        ]
\coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
\coordinate (xEnd) at (0,5);
\coordinate (yEnd) at (10.5,0);

\draw[->,thick,name path=xaxis] (origin) -- node [above,rotate=90] {Processors} (xEnd);
\draw[->,thick,name path=yaxis] (origin) -- node [below] {Time} (yEnd);

% first row
\node (src) at (0.5,3.3) [mybox=$src$];
\foreach \i in {0,1,...,5}
    \node [mybox=$radix_{\i}$];

\node [mybox=$src$,fill=gray!80];
    \foreach \i in {0,1,...,5}\node [mybox=$radix_{\i}$,fill=gray!80];

% second row
\node (r6) [mybox=$radix_{6}$,fill=gray!80,
            below right=of src.south west];
\foreach \i in {7,8,9,10}
    \node [mybox=$radix_{\i}$,fill=gray!80];
\node   [mybox=$output$,fill=gray!80];

\node [mybox=$radix_6$,right=7mm];
\foreach \i in {7,8,9,10}
    \node [mybox=$radix_{\i}$];
\node   [mybox=$output$,fill=gray!80];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Above I exploit the `chains` library and `node contents`. Tthe result is the same as it is provided by Svend Tveskeag